# What's the name of the music track that plays at 18:28 in Episode 150 of One Piece?

Tags: one-piece

What's the name of the music track that plays at about 18:28 in One Piece Episode 150 (Jaya Arc) when all of Bellamy's people are shocked on hearing about Luffy's and Zoro's real bounties as told by their drunken member?

Answer (score 1):

The song is called Shizuka na Ikari (静かな怒り). It is from the One Piece Original Soundtrack Album "Music and Song Collection 4", track number 16.

You can listen to it [here](https://youtu.be/yWSN--WupdM?t=1m27s).

Answer (score 0):

The song plays around crocodile a lot for some reason. 1:27 into "Shizuka Na Ikari"